# Is there a way to make a div take the height of the user's monitor resolution?

Tags: html, css

So I've created an index page which displays all images in my database, however, the width of the images is reduced to 500px. I've added the ability to click on the image and be sent to a page that displays the image in it's real dimensions, however, I would like to limit the high of the image to the resolution of the user's screen so the image is as big as possible without actually going off the screen. Any good way to do that?

Comment: So what you want is actually the height of the viewport? [That’s `100vh`.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: Did you even google for your question? You cannot possibly miss all the answers to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the div's height not larger than user's screen, just use `max-height: 100vh` rule.